# Replace all characters in a String, unless they are within double quotes

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am sadly unfamiliar with regular expressions since I'm not a programmer, but I would guess this problem is easily solvable using regex (I am definitely open to other suggestions, though)

I want to use the split function to split the value of a cell and spread it out over multiple cells. The delimiter is a comma. The problem though is that some users use commas in comments for example, which the Split function uses to split the string mid-comment.

for example a cell containing the value:

> 0001,"name","address","likes apples, oranges
>   and plums"

needs to be split into multiple cells saying 0001 "name" "address" and "likes apples, oranges and plums".

my code splits the comment as well, and I want it to ignore the comment or everything else withing double quotes. here is a sample:

```
Sub SplittingStrings()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim splitCount As Integer
    Dim splitString() As String
    Dim category As Variant

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    counter = 1

    For Each cell In Range("A1", "A2000")

        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            strInput = cell.Value
            splitCount = 2
            splitString = Split(strInput, ",")

            For Each category In splitString
                Cells(counter, splitCount).Value = category
                splitCount = splitCount + 1
            Next category
        End If

        counter = counter + 1

    Next cell


End Sub
```

how do I exclude stuff withing the double quotes from being considered by the split function?

Comment: You can use the built-in Excel "Text to Columns" and that will split it properly. No VBA needed.

Comment: @braX - if I understand the OP, which I may not, they don't want it split on commas inside quotes so "likes apples, oranges and plums" should be left alone.

Comment: @SJR - this is absolutely true, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: OK, are the quoted/non-quoted bits of text intermingled randomly or is there a pattern?

Comment: the pattern is pretty much what I tried to convey in my OP. it starts with an ID, then it goes through a bunch of tags which are all within double quotation marks and ends with a comment, which is also in double quotation and the only way a comma can actually appear within double quotation. The comment is user input and could be anything.

Comment: In that case why not split on `,"` and then remove any extraneous quote marks at the end with replace?

Comment: @SJR Text to columns handles that - it assumes the quote to be a text qualifier by default and will not split on commas within them.

Comment: @Rory - the light dawns, thanks. First comment solved it after all (I take it all back @braX)

Comment: Text to Columns will do what you want, differently than the split function.

Comment: Awesome, this totally solves it. Thank you. How do you flag a post as "solved in comments"? :)

Comment: You can't, can only ask @braX to post that as an answer.

Comment: @Otto I added it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try and see if you get the desired output.

Tweak the variables if required.

```
Sub SplittingStringsUsingRegEx()
Dim lr As Long, c As Long
Dim Rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim RE, Match, Matches

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("A1:A" & lr)

Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\d+|"".+?"""
End With

c = 2

For Each cell In Rng
    If RE.test(cell.Value) Then
        Set Matches = RE.Execute(cell.Value)
        For Each Match In Matches
            Cells(cell.Row, c) = Replace(Match, """", "")
            c = c + 1
        Next Match
    End If
    c = 2
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: [Output](https://regex101.com/r/obs8ID/1) of a test, so it seems it is working, however, a `"` was deleted to work, so in Excel does it have to be doubled `""` to recognize `"`?

Comment: That's correct. To input a double quote, you need to double the double quote. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without *Regex*:

We need to "protect" commas that are encapsulated with double quotes:

```
Sub ProtectStuff()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, v As String, v2 As String
    Dim ProtectMode As Boolean, DQ As String, rep As String
    Dim CH As String, arr

    DQ = """"
    rep = Chr(1)
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, "A").Value
        If v <> "" Then
            ProtectMode = False
            v2 = ""
            For j = 1 To Len(v)
                CH = Mid(v, j, 1)
                If CH = DQ Then ProtectMode = Not ProtectMode
                If CH = "," And ProtectMode Then CH = rep
                v2 = v2 & CH
            Next j
        End If

        arr = Split(v2, ",")
        j = 2
        For Each a In arr
            Cells(i, j) = Replace(a, rep, ",")
            j = j + 1
        Next a
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Text to Columns will do what you want, differently than the split function.